# Comparing each item from dir with each item from another dir

Tags: python, file-system

The task is to compare students homework SQL files with mentors SQL files.

I've written two functions, which return a two-dimensional array (1st elements are an absolute path, 2nd are a relative).

Then I'm going to compare the relative path of students and mentors and execute SQL files (finding using absolute path) if these values are equal

Is there a more elegant implementation?

The folder structure of mentors dir:

```
Homework (folder)
  ├ 1 (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
  ├ 2 (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
  ├ n (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
```

The folder structure of students dir:

```
├Students Homework (folder)
 ├Student1(folder)
  ├ 1 (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
  ├ 2 (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
  ├ n (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
 ├Student2(folder)
  ├ 1 (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
  ├ 2 (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
  ├ n (folder)
  | ├ 1.sql
  | ├ 2.sql
  | └ n.sql
```

"Mentors" function:

```py
def find_mentors_sql(config):

    mentors_sql_abs = []
    mentors_sql_rel = []

    for dirpath, subdirs, files in walk(config["MAIN_DIR"] + '\\Homework'):
        mentors_sql_abs.extend(path.join(dirpath, x) for x in files if x.endswith(".sql"))
        mentors_sql_rel.extend(path.join(path.basename(dirpath), x) for x in files if x.endswith(".sql"))

    mentors_sql = [[0] * 2 for i in range(len(mentors_sql_abs))]

    iter = 0
    for _ in mentors_sql_abs:
        mentors_sql[iter][0] = mentors_sql_abs[iter]
        iter += 1

    iter1 = 0
    for _ in mentors_sql_rel:
        mentors_sql[iter1][1] = mentors_sql_rel[iter1]
        iter1 += 1

    return mentors_sql
```

"Students" function (the logic is similar to the previous one:

````py
def find_students_sql(config):

    students_sql_abs = []
    students_sql_rel = []

    for dirpath, subdirs, files in walk(config["MAIN_DIR"] + '\\Students Homework'):
        students_sql_abs.extend(path.join(dirpath, x) for x in files if x.endswith(".sql"))
        students_sql_rel.extend(path.join(path.basename(dirpath), x) for x in files if x.endswith(".sql"))

    students_sql = [[0] * 2 for i in range(len(students_sql_abs))]

    iter = 0
    for _ in students_sql:
        students_sql[iter][0] = students_sql_abs[iter]
        iter += 1

    iter1 = 0
    for _ in students_sql:
        students_sql[iter1][1] = students_sql_rel[iter1]
        iter1 += 1

    return students_sql
```
````

Comment: Getting close to perfect there... Quick tips; _`for _ in <iterable>`_ could do without `iter = 0` stuff if ya use `enumerate()`, eg. _`for i, thing in enumerate(<iterable>)`_... though why you're pre-building an empty nested list is a little beyond me, I'd use a `list` of `tuples` or a `dict`ionary... Looks like the `find_mentors_sql` and `find_students_sql` could be merged into one function, and I think _`walk_path = os.path.join(p1, p2)`_ you'll find more portable than `walk`ing `p1 + '\\p2'`... finally for this comment, those one-liner `for` loops with `extend` hurt the code's readability.

Comment: @S0AndS0 Comments are for seeking clarification to the question, and may be deleted. Please put all suggestions for improvements in answers.

Comment: Wups @200_success, I'll attempt to do better in the future, for now my attempt at an answer will go into trying to address _`"Is there a more elegant implementation?"`_, because I spent a little more time with the code.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's recommended to use `enumerate` rather than `iter` (renamed `i`), `_` and indexing.

   ```
   for i, abs_path in enemerate(mentors_sql_abs):
       mentors_sql[i][0] = abs_path
   ```
2. It's better to use `zip` rather than build `mentors_sql` manually.
3. Your function could further be simplified if you don't extend `mentors_sql_*` and just `yield` the values.
4. Please only use one string delimiter, either `'` or `"`.
5. `x` is a pretty bad variable name, I would use `file`. Even for a comprehension it's pretty poor, as x isn't short hand for anything.
6. The only difference between the two functions as you walk different paths. And so you can change your input to account for this, and use one function.
7. I don't see the need for returning both relative and absolute paths, and so won't comment on it too much. You may want to return one and convert when needed.

```
def find_sql(path):
    for dirpath, subdirs, files in walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.sql'):
                yield (
                    path.join(dirpath, file),
                    path.join(path.basename(dirpath), file)
                )


mentors = find_sql(config["MAIN_DIR"] + '\\Homework')
students = find_sql(config["MAIN_DIR"] + '\\Students Homework')
```

Comment: `iter` is also a built-in being shadowed here (although you don't use it in the end).

Comment: I agree in general. But when actually iterating over something, calling the iterating variable `iter` can be quite confusing IMO.

Comment: @Graipher I agree `iter` is a terrible variable name. It doesn't matter if it's it's shadowing a builtin or not, it's just bad.

Comment: Working through a back log of about a year of comments? In any case, I agree, although I'm also not a big fan of my usual choice of `it`.

Comment: @Graipher Something like that yeah. Hadn't seen you around either so had to give you a ping ;P Hmm, I've seen `it` for iterator/iterable, I think `i` is ok but not great - at least it's kinda a standard.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I spent just a little while with your code @Valentyn, and I think it is mostly unharmed...

#### `sql_utils/__init__.py`

```py
import os


def walked_sql_paths(config, sub_dir):
    """
    Generates `tuple` of absolute and relative file paths

    - `config` should contain a 'MAIN_DIR' key with a value similar to
        - `/home/Mentor`
        - `/home/StudentName`
    - `sub_dir` should contain a string such as `Homework`
    """
    ## ... I am guessing that ya might be doing something
    ##     else with the `config` object, if this is not
    ##     the case, then this could be simplified to
    ##     only taking a `path` argument instead.
    target_dir = os.path.join(config['MAIN_DIR'], sub_dir)

    for dirpath, subdirs, files in walk(target_dir):
        for item in files:
            if not item.endswith('.sql'):
                continue

            sql_abs = os.path.join(dirpath, item)
            sql_rel = os.path.basename(dirpath)
            yield sql_abs, sql_rel
```

> That *stuff* between `"""` (triple quotes) be a [*`"docstring"`*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring), and is accessable via either `help(walked_sql_paths)` or `print(walked_sql_paths.__doc__)`. The [*`"dunder"`*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunder) or [*`"Magic Method"`*](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/) stuff I'll not cover here as that's a whole *'nother-can-o-worms*. What is important is that accessible documentation is something that Python allows for, while code that doesn't require it is something to strive for.

I'm using [*`yield`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/2632107) in the above `for` loop so that it yields partial results to whatever calls `next()` or `__next__()` methods (called by `for` loops and other processes implicitly), [`generators`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) are a *cheep* way of optimizing code as well as ensuring that users experience less *herky jerky* loading between results; even if things are taking awhile this'll usually *feel* faster in other-words.

The assignments of `sql_abs` and `sql_rel` are first for readability, and second for making it easy to later do something like *`yield sql_rel, sql_abs`* instead. Otherwise there's little reason to prefer it over the answer posted by [@Peilonrayz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/219322/197446).

Here's one way of using the above modified code...

```py
from sql_utils import walked_sql_paths


## ... setting of `mentors` and `students` `_config` objects
##     and other stuff I am guessing will go here...


students_paths = walked_sql_paths(config = students_config,
                                  sub_dir = 'Students Homework')

mentors_paths = walked_sql_paths(config = mentors_config,
                                 sub_dir = 'Homework')


for s_paths, m_paths in zip(students_paths, mentors_paths):
    if not s_paths[0] == m_paths[0]:
        print("Warning, continuing past -> {s_rel_path} and {m_rel_path} miss-match!".format(
            s_rel_path = s_path[0],
            m_rel_path = m_path[0]))
        continue

    print("Time to compare -> Mentors {m_abs_path} with Students {s_abs_path}".format(
        m_abs_path = m_paths[1],
        s_abs_path = s_paths[1]))
```

I'm using [*`zip`*](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to zip-up the two generators in the above `for` loop because it's a built-in that seems to do what ya want.

Hopefully none of this is *mind blowing* because like I stated in your question's comments @Valentyn, you where really close to something that I'd not be able to add to.

---

Looking at the folder structure a bit closer, it looks like things'll could get just a bit *fancier* with the loops. What's your preference on ordering?

My thoughts would be to iterate over *`Students_Homework/`* of students and then *`zip`-up* between sub-folders, in which case it maybe possible to *cache* the Mentor's folders on the first pass. However, that would not be nice to scale or if there's lots of sub-directories... Another thought would be to iterate over the Mentor's `1`-`n` folders and `zip`-up on each student in turn. Feel free to comment with a preference as to which might be more helpful.

---

Thoughts on the future, using `try`/`except` you can code for cases where, *`Student3`* didn't turn in the *`5.sql`* file espected in *`2`'s folder*, so here's some *skeleton-code* that'll hopefully get ya a little closer to fault tolerantness...

```py
def safety_zipper(*iters, search_strs):
  """
  Allows for doing something _clever_ where things could have gone painfully wrong

  - `iters`, `list` of iterables that each output `tuple`s of length two `(rel_path, abs_path)`
  - `search_strs`, `list` of `str`ings to search for matches on `rel_path`

  Yields `list` of `tuple`s `(rel_path, abs_path)`
  """
  for search_str in search_strs:
      partial_results = []
      for thing in iters:
          try:
              path_tuple = thing.next()
          except (GeneratorExit, StopIteration):
              ## Note passing can be dangerous, I only do it
              ##  because the parent loop will exit, eventually
              print("Warning {abs_path} miss-match with {search_str}".format(
                  abs_path = path_tuple[1],
                  search_str = search_str))
              pass
          else:  ## No error so do things with next thing
              ## Uncomment the following if useful
              # abs_path = path_tuple[1]
              rel_path = path_tuple[0]
              if search_str == rel_path:
                  partial_results.append(path_tuple)
                  continue

              ## Deal with miss-matches in a clever way here, such
              ##  as if a student is late to turn in an assignment.

          finally:
              ## Finally runs regardless, well so long as another
              ##  exception is not raised before reaching here.
              ##  Only included for completeness and in-case ya
              ##  wanted to do something fancy here too.
              pass

      yield partial_results
```

... I'll warn that the above is not complete, but essentially it'll allow for catching cases where *`Student`* directories or files do not match those of the *`Mentor`'s* file paths. It may have to be *stacked* to be able to check for differences in both directories and files, and pre-loading `search_strs` list would either require foreknowledge or pre-parsing a chunk of *`Mentor`'s* file paths to populate.

But whatever's *downstream* will have a much cleaner input and require much less edge-case detection.